# Laravel 5.2 Form inside a @foreach

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-form

I try to put a form inside a foreach loop. The code is:

```
@foreach( $document_rows as $row )

    <?php
        $idx      = $row->id;
        $product  = Product::find( $row->product_id );
        $vat      = Vat::find( $row->vat_id );
        $tot_riga = floatval($row->price) * intval($row->product_quantity);
    ?>

    {!! Form::open([
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'route' => [ 'document.row.update', $document->id, $row->id ],
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    ]) !!}

    <tr class="document_row">
        <td
            id="field_id-{{ $idx }}"
            readonly="true"
            data-field="id"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $idx }}
        </td>
        <td
            class="field"
            id="field_name-{{$idx}}"
            data-field="name"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $row->product_name }}
        </td>
        <td
            class="field"
            id="field_um-{{$idx}}"
            data-field="um"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $row->product_um }}
        </td>
        <td
            class="field"
            id="field_quantity-{{ $idx }}"
            data-field="quantity"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $row->product_quantity }}
        </td>
        <td
            class="field"
            id="field_price-{{ $idx }}"
            data-field="price"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $row->price }}
        </td>
        <td
            class="field"
            id="field_vat-{{ $idx }}"
            data-field="vat"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $vat->name }}
        </td>
        <td
            class="field"
            id="field_price_inc_vat-{{ $idx }}"
            data-field="price_inc_vat"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $row->price_inc_vat }}
        </td>
        <td
            id="field_tot_riga-{{ $idx }}"
            readonly="true"
            data-field="tot_riga"
            data-id="{{ $idx }}"
        >
            {{ $tot_riga }}
        </td>
    </tr>

    {!! Form::close() !!}

@endforeach
```

Problem are that form tag close immediately:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/site/public/document/1/row/update/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal"></form><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="62PHHV4cnYmVOVQkkV43UCWdTkbE3tpo0OIUxuCx">
<tr class="document_row">
    <td id="field_id-1" readonly="true" data-field="id" data-id="1" tabindex="1">1</td>
    <td class="field" id="field_name-1" data-field="name" data-id="1" tabindex="1"></td>
    <td class="field" id="field_um-1" data-field="um" data-id="1" tabindex="1">nr</td>
    <td class="field" id="field_quantity-1" data-field="quantity" data-id="1" tabindex="1">100</td>
    <td class="field" id="field_price-1" data-field="price" data-id="1" tabindex="1">13</td>
    <td class="field" id="field_vat-1" data-field="vat" data-id="1" tabindex="1">Iva 22%</td>
    <td class="field" id="field_price_inc_vat-1" data-field="price_inc_vat" data-id="1" tabindex="1">15</td>
    <td id="field_tot_riga-1" readonly="true" data-field="tot_riga" data-id="1" tabindex="1">1300</td>
</tr>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: use `form` inside the `td` tag

Comment: i have already tried, but the results is the same!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't put form inner table.
Try this.

```
   <form>
     @foreach()
       <table> .... </table>
     @endforeach
  </form>
```

***Note***: Browsers manipulate html tags.

Comment: Hello, i leaved tables for a most convenient div's layout and all works!!

Comment: Yea, div system better than table also you can use them for resposive.